# django having multiple one many to many relations that references same model

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

i have a model that is having multiple many to many relation to another model it is as follows:

```
class Match(models.Model):
"""Model docstring"""
   Match_Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   Team_one = models.ManyToManyField('Team',related_name='Team one',symmetrical=False,) 
   Team_two = models.ManyToManyField('Team',related_name='Team two',symmetrical=False,) 
   stadium = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   Start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
   Rafree = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   Judge = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   winner = models.ForeignKey('Team', related_name='winner',to_field='Team_Name')    
   updated = models.DateTimeField('update date', auto_now=True )
   created = models.DateTimeField('creation date', auto_now_add=True )
```

what is the best way to implement model like this ?. all though django does not throw any errors when passing the model sql once syncdb is excuted it throws up errors saying `there is no unique constraint matching given keys`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `Team_one` and `Team_two` should be ManyToMany fields? Surely, a match only has a single team on each side - in which case these should both be ForeignKeys.

Comment: your are right it should be foreignkeys. I have changed it to foriegnkeys but still getting the same `there is no unique constraint matching given keys`error

Answer (score 1):

Using spaces in `related_name` attribute makes me uneasy, but I think the real problem is connected to the use of `to_field` attribute on the `winner` field. As far as I know you can set database relations only to `unique` fields. It doesn't really make sense to relate to another object using a field that may not be unique.

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve by connecting through this particular field. You usually connect models using primary key fields. This still allows you to access any other field on the related object.

Comment: i have actually the `winner` field and the error is still persisting  The problem seems that both `team_one` and `team_two` fields is having same relation to `Team` Model.

Comment: "i have actually the winner field" - I think you've lost a word in the sentence. "Actually removed"?

Comment: yea sorry bit early in the morning here so missing stuff. I removed the field. Any way i figured out what the problem was. IT was not creating constraints because i had a custom primary key defined as soon as i removed it's working now.